# Building a dynamic regex that ignores white spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

So i'm trying to to match a word ignoring white spaces and since there is no flag for this i had to insert `\s*` between each character but the struggle im having is how to do that dynamically ... here is what i have tried :

```js
 const regArray = ['S','o','m','e','W','o','r','d']
 var index = 1
  regArray.forEach((element) => {
       regArray.splice(index, 0 ,'\s*')
       index = index + 2
  });
  regArray.splice(-1,1)
  const regex = RegExp(regArray.join('')+'.*','i')
  console.log(regex) // Ss*os*ms*es*Ws*os*rs*d.*/i
  // expected S\s*o\s*.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of joining with empty string join with `\\s*`, also no need to use `forEach` and `splice`

```js
const regArray = ['S', 'o', 'm', 'e', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'd']
const regex = RegExp(regArray.join('\\s*'), 'i')

console.log(regex) // Ss*os*ms*es*Ws*os*rs*d.*/i
// expected S\s*o\s*.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of all this trouble of using arrays and splices you can use a replace regexp to have the input as a string.

```
const string = "SomeWord".replace(/(\w)/g, "$1\\s*")
// expected: "S\s*o\s*m\s*e\s*W\s*o\s*r\s*d\s*"
const regexp = RegExp(string)
// expected: /S\s*o\s*m\s*e\s*W\s*o\s*r\s*d\s*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
   console.log (RegExp ("Someword".split ('').join ('\\s*'), 'i'));
```